# Deriving the Exact Percentage Change Formula in Logarithmic Models

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, logarithm

[image]I have been studying the relationship between logarithmic changes and percentage changes in the context of regression analysis. I understand that when working with small changes, the change in the logarithm of a variable can be approximated as the percentage change in the variable itself. However, I am now looking at the exact percentage change in the context of a logarithmic regression model, and I'm trying to grasp the derivation of the following equation which calculates the exact percentage change in the predicted outcome:

The estimated model is:
$$\widehat{\log(y)} = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 \log(x_1) + \hat{\beta}_2 x_2$$

Upon adding additional independent variables and fixing, we consider a change in leading to:
$$ \Delta \widehat{\log(y)} = \hat{\beta}_2 \Delta x_2
$$

Using simple algebraic properties of the exponential and logarithmic functions, the text states that this leads to the exact percentage change in the predicted y ​as:
$$ \% \Delta\hat{y} = 100 \cdot [\exp(\hat{\beta}_2 \Delta x_2) - 1] $$

**However, I am uncertain how we go from the change in the log of
$\widehat{\log(y)}$ to the percentage change formula stated above. Could anyone explain the derivation of equation 6.8 or provide any resources that walk through this calculation?**

For further context, the equations and model in question are taken from Chapter 6, specifically Section 6-2, of Jeffrey M. Wooldridge's "Introduction to Econometrics 7e".

Comment: The derivation relies on the definition of a percentage and basic properties of logarithms.  There's nothing deep or even statistical about this -- maybe realizing it's so simple will help you see better what's going on.

Comment: @whuber Yeah, I think I get it now. The term $ \exp(x)−1$ represents the continuous growth rate, similar to how continuous compounding is calculated in finance, so when multiplied by 100 it converts this growth rate into a percentage right?

Comment: That's right: it's the same math.